# Test folder does not exist because I used -T, can I add it somehow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, minitest

I created my Rails project with the -T option because I was following a tutorial that was using Rspec.

Now I want to test using Minitest so I can follow the Rails doc but the directories were not created upon creating the models because I skipped that step with -T.

Can I modify the Gemfile to unistall Rspec and run something in the command line to generate the files and directories for Minitest? Or do I have to start the project over?

Comment: This might help https://adlerhsieh.com/blog/minitest-setup-for-rails

Comment: Excellent thank you!